# JS function to print a doc file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printing

I am trying to print a doc file located in my server using a js function.
At first, I thought it is going to an easy task, but after a lot of research I can not find a way to do that.

I have tried this, but the result is a page with the url in the content of it.

```
$('#printItems').on('click', '.toPrint', function(e){
        console.log("Printing...");
        e.preventDefault();
        doc = $(this).attr( "href" );
        var w = window.open(doc);
        w.document.write(doc);
        w.print();
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I know that google doc has the option to do that. Does it convert the file to PDF and use pdf.js ?

Comment: Do you mean a doc file as in, a Microsoft Word document? That's not gonna be possible to do directly in the browser. You're gonna have to let the user download the file and print it themselves from Microsoft Word.

Comment: Why are you calling `write`?

Comment: Thanks, I think I am going to let the user download it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no proper way to directly write in file using javascript.
You can use other programming language like java,c. They providing direct access to create files and read/write them

Comment: You can't use Java or C in the browser and the question isn't asking about writing to files, it is asking about **printing** (as in ink and paper).